# How Can I destroy a jquery slideshow and load elements with default style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am using a jquery slideshow plugin called [superslides](https://github.com/nicinabox/superslides). I wanted to implement a multi styled page for my [quote site](http://quotewe.blogspot.in/). By default the slideshow plugin is initiated. I need to destroy the slide effect on button click and load grid view for my  elements.
I have tried removing the id for the slideshow markup and then do an ajax load,but it doesn't work!
This jquery plugin has a destroy api `$('#slides').superslides('destroy')`.

```
<div id="slides">
  <div class="slides-container">
    <h2>This is a quote</h2>
    <h2>This is another</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the `destroy` option isn't working for you, the next best thing might be to [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone) the container element in a global variable before you convert it to a slideshow:

```
$pre_slideshow = $('#slides').clone();
$('#slides').superslides();
// later, when you want to restore it....
$('#slides').replaceWith($pre_slideshow);
```

Comment: The destroy element deletes the entire above code and I don't want to delete the elements in it!

Comment: That's pretty poor design on the plugin developer's part, if you ask me. You should tell them so.

Comment: Hey,is there any other way of achieving a grid view and a slide view for my site?

Comment: what should I google? CSS style switchers don't work in this case,right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for. In any case, it's a separate question from the one you've already asked here.